# How can I import X number of dummy users into OpenLDAP?

Tags: java, openldap

Okay so I wrote code to generate X number of dummy ldif user files. What I need to do is some metrics on loading of all of the users into memory and capture the memory performance on the server. What I'm trying to figure out is

- Do I cycle over every single ldif file and call OpenLdap to add the user?

  ```
  ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=ramesh,dc=tgs,dc=com" -f adam.ldif
  ```
- Is there a way to put all of the users into a single file and process just 1 file?
- Or is there a documented right way to do this?

I read something about OpenLDAP Client Tools

- Is this how a 100k new test users can be added quicker than writing a JAVA program to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-3. Add them all into a single LDIF file. It's documented.

4. Yes.

Comment: Okay, so one way is to as stated above put all of the entries into a single LDIF file. 

Then (in my case) use the import feature from the OpenLDAP utility to load the users into LDAP. 

The other way I'm going to look into is 'ldapmodify' but for now this answer works for me.